# Can't verify file input element after selecting file through selenium web driver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Can't verify file input element after selecting file through selenium web driver

I have input "Choose File" to select the file but after selecting file, DOM doesn't reflect the selected file. Is there any way to identify whether particular file name element present, may be using java script?

Html code doesn't reflect profile.reg element in DOM according to screenshot. You can notice that profile.reg doesn't exist in DOM at all.

I'm expecting something like:

```
WebElement we = getElementOrNull("input[id='ZmImportView_FILE']:contains('profile.reg')");
visible = we.isDisplayed();
```

[image]

Comment: Check the `value` property on the `input` element. That should contain the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
WebElement we = null;
we = webDriver.findElement(By.id("ZmImportView_FILE"));
if (we.getAttribute("value").contains(fileName)) {
    System.out.println(we.getAttribute("value"));
}
```

It shows file path if file is shown after selecting it properly. Thanks Anthony!